# Getting output of curl command in a variable

Tags: unix, curl, output

I need to fetch data out of a cloud platform. The process to export data is 2 step:

1. First make a post call with the username/password details. This will return xml output with a jobid in the response.
2. Fetch the jobid from the first response and use this jobid, concatenate it to get a new url and then make a get call (execute curl again) using this new url, I will then get data in a json response.

**What I did:**
I am able to make the first API call and get the jobID. Next,I concatenated this jobId to get new url and saved complete curl statement in a variable (lets call the variable cmd_second_api_call). This variable 'cmd_second_api_call' contains the complete curl statement that I need to execute.
So I did a out=$($cmd_second_api_call), as I want to execute the second curl statement and store the output in a variable.

**Problem:**
When I execute out=$($cmd_second_api_call), I see out variable as empty. I verified $cmd_second_api_call actually outputs the curl command perfectly. If I execute the output of $cmd_second_api_call on my command prompt I see the output. What am I missing here? How to get the curl output in a variable?

Thanks!

```
r=$(curl -k -u user:password static_url -d <data I need to pass>)

jobid=$(echo $r | sed -n 's:.*<jobid>\(.*\)<\/jobid>.*:\1:p')

second_url="abc.com/${jobid}/result/ --get -d output=json"

cmd_second_api_call="curl -u user:password -k ${second_url}"

out=$($cmd_second_api_call)

echo $out
```

Comment: First get used to quotes. With `out="String with           spaces and wildcard *"` you will have diffferent results with `echo $out` and `echo "$out"`.

Comment: Perhaps try `out=$(curl -u user:password -k ${second_url})` or `out=$(curl -u user:password -k abc.com/${jobid}/result/ --get -d output=json)`

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Also, I had to add a **sleep 5** statement before calling the second api as I got a no data response (response code 204) without the sleep statment. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting a command in a variable or using variables without quotes can be dangerous.
I suggested

```
out=$(curl -u user:password -k ${second_url})
# or 
out=$(curl -u user:password -k abc.com/${jobid}/result/ --get -d output=json) 
# and
echo "$out"
```

Somehow this helped, together with a `sleep 5` between both `curl` calls. You wouldn't expect a lag at the remote server between returning a valid jobid and enabling the interface for that jobid. Perhaps some kind of "defence" against unauthorized calls with random jobid's.